# Google Sheets: Formula that checks if a specific string repeats down any number of rows between two surrounding strings?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

[Sample data here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17V62b_M1a9zMUnrdPbqbN-gwGXTaYmUkgDjTdkJPy1A/edit?usp=sharing)

In my sheet, I mark header rows in the A-column. If all rows between any given header row are marked as "Ignore" in the B-column, then I'd like that header column to format to a different color.

How do you build a formala that can check if the string "Ignore" happens on any number of rows between two A-column cells with a given string?

Checking for an unknown number of rows is beyond my skillset in formula-building.

**EDIT:**

I've added a few new conditions that make this slightly more complicated.

1. A top header row, which should be ignored.
2. Some rows in column A have data in non-header rows. So, the dynamic range has to check for the exact string that marks a header row and how many rows it takes before that string repeats in the column.
3. Some B-column rows are blank. Blank doesn't mean "Ignore", so if all B-column rows beneath a header are blank, the header shouldn't have the special format.

Comment: Make it accessable to everyone with a link ... Link page show "You need access"

Comment: Share the link with everyone, [Request access](https://i.imgur.com/Kvy5SZU.png)

Comment: @Osm My bad, sharing permissions updated. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=(NOT(REGEXMATCH(ROW($A1)&"", INDEX(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "×", 
 IFERROR(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(VLOOKUP(ROW($A1:$A), 
 IF($A1:$A<>"", {ROW($A1:$A), ROW($A1:$A)}), 2, 1), 
 $B1:$B<>"Ignore", $B1:$B<>"")), 1, 0)))))))*($A1<>"")
```

[image]

[image]

---

## update:

```
=NOT(REGEXMATCH(ROW($A2)&"",  "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, "×", 
 IFERROR(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF(($A2:$A<>"")*($A2:$A<>"*"),, ROW($A2:$A)),   
 IF(($A2:$A<>"")*($A2:$A<>"*"), {ROW($A2:$A), ROW($A2:$A)}), 2, 1)), 
 $B2:$B<>"ignore", $C2:$C<>"")), 1, 0)))&"$"))*($A2<>"")*($A2<>"*")
```

[image]

### [step-by-step formula explanation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TaNGvJI8WA0Ez5kYiba3Eq58E-GU5uP6RDoaIFe3xsU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Not the entire row just the column header see his comment on my answer.

Comment: @Osm still, fx is same. updated

Comment: @pgSystemTester indeed. fixed, answer updated. ty

Comment: Nice. I sometimes have a hard time following your formulas, and this one is.... no exception. :) Definitely works though.

Comment: I'm in awe of formula building of this depth. I'm going to accept pgSystemTester's answer because more concise and easier to grasp, but this is much appreciated anyway.

Comment: @gills happy to explain if you wish

Comment: @gills answer updated

Comment: @pgSystemTester answer updated

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as `Player()` only a little shorter formula.

```
=if(A1<>"",len(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",,B2
:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(true,isblank(B2:B),0)+row()-1,1)),"Ignore",""))=0,"")
```

[image]

### Explanation of Dynamic Range

The hardest part of this is matching the groups of values in column b. To do this, I used a vector approach of with an `index` function separating the ranges with a  `:`. So like one would do `B2:B3`, one could do: `B2:Index`.

To get the lower position, I used a method of matching the first blank (note ="" won't work). This will identify the distance from the cell the function is being called from. We then need to add the row it's being called from, then one cell higher (less) as we don't want the blank cell, but the one above. So combining... `INDEX(B:B,MATCH(true,isblank(B2:B),0)+row()-1,1)` gets the dynamic lower value.

After that, there's a variety of ways to solve. I used textjoin and substation to confirm a length of zero as a method, but lots of other ways.

Comment: Still trying to grasp the explanation, but with a little editing, this worked perfectly for me, thank you! I've added some new conditions to my question, see above. I was able to adjust your formula to meet them (and also format the whole header row, not just the A cell): `=if($A1="header",len(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",,$B2 :INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(true,isblank($B2:$B),0)+row()-1,1)),"Ignore",""))=0,"")`. Perhaps you can update your answer with this adjustment and I can accept it as the solution? Thanks again!

Comment: Shoot, I spoke too soon. Please see my third condition I've just added, which even my adjustment formula doesn't seem to meet. How might I fix this?

Comment: I'm not going to update the answer as I put in an explanation that would need to be rewritten. However, looking at your formula, it's not hard to adjust the matching technique. Rather than looking in column b for a blank, we can look to column A for a non blank and if none exists just use last row in column. So updating YOUR formula would be this...  `=if($A1="header",len(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",,$B2 :INDEX($B:$B,iferror(match(true,not(isblank(A2:A)),0)+Row(),rows($B:$B)),1)),"Ignore",""))=0,"")`

Answer (score 0):

> **Paste** this: formula in `C1`, to get a helper column that can be hidden.

```
=AND( A1<>"", LOWER(B2)= "ignore")
```

> **Paste** this: formula in conditional formatting and set Apply to range to `A1:A1000`, take a look at [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DhvePVSfHYXPuWBzJrjd3zwNRX3kpBWTjfK-iGEvNvo/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=$B:$B="Ignore"
```

[image]

Comment: @player0 yes, [`=B1="Ignore"`](https://i.imgur.com/2Z4KBpv.png)  format one column but [`=$B1="Ignore"`](https://i.imgur.com/YdXT9v9.png) highlight all columns in Ignore row.

Comment: Thanks! But this isn't what I'm trying to achieve. It's the header column that I want to conditionally format. And I only want the header column to be formatted if all rows beneath it say "Ignore" (until the next header column).

Comment: Check @Player0 answer tested in the [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DhvePVSfHYXPuWBzJrjd3zwNRX3kpBWTjfK-iGEvNvo/edit#gid=1784128658)

Comment: This won't work. change cell `b10` to `nope` and row 8 will give a false positive.

Comment: this formula or player0 answer works with `Ignore`, if you want to use `nope` as a indicator change it to a cell refrence

Comment: ‍♂️ omg... no