# Google sheets - Conditional Formatting "less than" not working properly when used on range

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, formatting, conditional-formatting

t Hey guys, im getting mad about something really simple. Why does this plain conditional formatting light up the values 15 and 12? When applied only for cell D1 or F1 it works properly, I'm really clueless. Thank you for your advice!

Also my greetings got deleted everytime after saving the edit, I had to put a random letter in front so it got through, whats up with that random behaviour lol

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of your:

```
=A1
```

use:

```
=$A1
```

Comment: Why is this necessary, if you got the time? Greatly appreciate you, thanks!

Comment: @Hellooo $ will lock it. $A will lock down the column, $1 will lock down row and $A$1 will lock down the column & row. if you do not lock it with $ it will continue the iteration over the whole specified range. see your image in your question... D1 got painted green coz C1 is more than D1 eg. by not locking the A1 cell it will move with every next cell.

Comment: @player0 like the one we attempted to solve yesterday, but unfortunately I didn't find a definitive solution. Can you help on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73203915/19529694)?

Comment: @Osm sure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73226108/5632629